# Find the value of $G^4_1+2G^4_2+G^4_3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $m$ is the A.M. of two distinct real numbers $l$ and $n$ $(l,n>1)$ and 
>   $G_1$, $G_2$ and $G_3$ are three G.M's between $l$ and $n$.
>   $G^4_1+2G^4_2+G^4_3$ equals .

**Options**

$\begin{align}&(1.)\quad 4lmn^2\\
&(2.)\quad 4l^2m^2n^2\\
&(3.)\quad 4l^2mn\\
&(4.)\quad 4lm^2n\\\end{align}$

so far from A.M and G.M property  i have

$m=\dfrac{l+n}{2}\\~\\
\dfrac{l}{G_1}=\dfrac{G_1}{G_2}=\dfrac{G_2}{G_3}=\dfrac{G_3}{n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that $l$ is the first term and $n$ is the last term. Now, we need to insert $3$  G.M's between $l$ and $ m$ so we have
From the formula

- $T^{nth} = a\cdot r^{n-1}$  (where $a$ is the first term and $r$ the common ratio)

  we have

$n=l r^{5-1} \implies $$\frac n l =r^4$
 $\implies r=(\frac n l)^{1/4}$

Now $G_1$ = $ar = l(\dfrac{n}{l})^{1/4} $

So,

$ G_1^4 = l^3 n$

Similarly $G_2^4 = l^2 n^2$ and $G_3^4 = l n^3$

$\begin{align}G_1^4 + 2G_2^4 + G_3^4 
&= l^3n+2l^2 n^2 + l n^3 \\
&= ln(l^2+2nl+n^2)\\
&= ln(l+n)^2 \\&= ln(2m)^2\\& = 4m^2ln\end{align}$

Comment: Can u edit it in latex.

Comment: I don't know how to :(

Comment: Use this [link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)